# Properly display tags within Ruby comments

Tags: ruby

I see in the Ruby core library source they sometimes have large blocks of comments with

```
<code>some code</code>
```

and

```
+someMethodName+
```

in them.  I suppose the code tag is supposed to be rendered by the code editor.  What IDE does it properly?  I'm using Rubymine.

The attached image is how it looks for me:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not supposed to be rendered by a code editor, it's rendered by RDoc. Some editors *can* display the information, but unless they implement everything RDoc does the resulting output will have artifacts.

See [the RDoc documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/rdoc/rdoc/index.html) and the associated [README](https://github.com/rdoc/rdoc/blob/master/README.rdoc) for more information about how and what it does.